# How Many Nodes Does Famo.us Support

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I am in the process of researching JS libraries with Scene Graph features.

My app could have 10k+ nodes (which I believe are called Surfaces in famo.us terminology) depending on how I write it.

How many Surfaces can famo.us reliably support while translating, rotating, and zooming, without much if any visual delays?

Please post examples if you know of them.

Comment: @talves I am always a little suspicious of these scene graph libs when they do not provide perf tests with many thousands of nodes.  Are you speaking from experience with Famous or with JS or HTML Canvas?

Comment: Famous has great performance from experience, but yours is a pretty tall order. [See http://jsbin.com/bucade/edit?js,output using newer engine](http://jsbin.com/bucade/edit?js,output) and click on any moving logo to add more nodes.